# Autorun desktop app and check if it is running from a Windows 8 App

Tags: windows-8.1, autorun, windows-embedded

I´m developing a Windows 8 App, and it needs a desktop app running on background to work properly.

So i have two questions:

1.- The OS is a Windows 8.1 Industry Embedded. I need to autorun the desktop app and my Windows 8 app at startup.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451259.aspx) explains how to do so with a Windows 8 App, but not with a desktop app, so i´m using [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/28206/windows-8-how-to-add-applications-startup-folder/) other solution to add the application to the Windows Startup folder, but i´m not sure if this is the best way.

2.- Then, when my app starts, i should check if the other app is running or not to work in one way or another. How can i check that? I´m developing with HTML and Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes that is the 'proper' solution to starting a desktop app on startup. Otherwise you can look at creating a windows service that manages the app lifecycle.
2. By design, winRT apps are not supposed to talk to desktop applications, but if you are sideloading the winRT app (i.e., not through the Windows Store), you could run a local server with your desktop app, and then enable local loopback with localhost in your winRT app and communicate that way.